# How run rdesktop after install it?

Tags: 14.04, rdesktop

I just installed rdesktop on Ubuntu 14.04 and I type rdesktop on the search to try to run it and nothing show. Is rdesktop a UI app? How can I run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rdesktop from terminal.

If you just type `rdesktop` you will get all the options it provides (oddly it has no man entry on my system).

An example of usage:

```
rdesktop -u username -g 100% -PKD 192.168.1.50
```

In this example `-u` is user and `-g` is screen size. You can do cool things like pass a resolution and other stuff. All the explanation is shown to you if you enter `rdesktop` without any arguments.

Comment: What I  want is uses it as a UI app, is that possible?

Comment: @gsi-frank you can probably use remmina

Comment: You can try grdesktop, its in the 14.04 repos: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=grdesktop&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all

Comment: @alci Remmina have a bug with the sound through RDP

Comment: @gsi-frank then grdestop might be what you want. apt-get install gredesktop